# Get only users with TransitiveMembers Microsoft Graph C# SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to get all users that are member of a group (transitive).
This call gets what I want:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{guid}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user
```

In my C# application I use the Graph API SDK. I know how you specify queryoptions, but I need an url segment instead of a query options.

At the moment I have this:

```
graphClient.Groups[guid].TransitiveMembers.Request().Select("id").GetAsync();
```

This returns all members, but not only users. So if someone know how to achieve this with the C# sdk please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The provided request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user
```

could be constructed and executed via [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) like this:

```
var requestUrl = $"{graphClient.Groups[groupId].TransitiveMembers.Request().RequestUrl}/microsoft.graph.user";
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
```

and the response de-serialized like this:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var json = JObject.Parse(content);
    var items = json["value"].Where(i =>  (string)i["@odata.type"] == null);
    var members = items.Select(item => item.ToObject<Microsoft.Graph.User>());

    foreach (var member in members)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(member.UserPrincipalName);                     
    }
}
```

---

Since the query `/groups/{group-id}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user` still returns the collection of *all* transitive members but *only* the properties for `microsoft.graph.user` object are retrieved meaning it is not working precisely the same way as [$filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter), maybe a more straightforward way would be:

a) retrieve all the  transitive members via request:

```
var members = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].TransitiveMembers.Request().GetAsync();
```

b) and filter by user type:

```
var userMembers = members.Where(m => m.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.user").Cast<User>();
foreach (var member in userMembers)
{
     Console.WriteLine(member.UserPrincipalName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about those two options, but I hoped there was a default method or something within the SDK to solve this.

Comment: @FerronSW, regarding default method, unfortunately nope, at least not im aware of.